# How to Rotate image before displaying in web using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to know, can I detect attributes of an image before displaying it on the web? In my case, I have a thousand photos. I want to display them on my web page but some photos have a different orientation (like Landscape and Portrait).

Can I detect the width and height of the image before it is displayed on my web page?

Maybe using JavaScript like:

```
If height>width than rotate
else just display.
```

Is there any JavaScript function for doing that? Just for getting the attribute not displaying it. Is there a trick?

Answer (score 1):

When your page is loading, you can control each `<img/>`

```
//function rotation
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

// When your page is loading
$( window ).load(function() {
    // Each image, you can change selector
    $('img').each(function(){
        if(this.height() < this.width()){ // Size control
            $(this).rotate(90); // rotation function call with the angle in degrees
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $(window).load is after all the images are loaded not when it is loading. This will work but after all the images are loaded.

Comment: I doubt the speed in case of loading a thousand photo as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, but it's very fast, you can use `animate()` to create something more beautiful. You can also add `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` on all your img. And change this displaying in the `each()`

Comment: sorry i am still newbie, in your answer, are you using jquery external function?

Comment: `.load()`, `.each()`, `.height()`, `.width()` are native function in jQuery. `rotate` is a function that I create to rotate an element and which is supported in many browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until it is loaded.

```
setInterval(function () {
   if(loaded)
   {
      clearInterval(wait);
   }
   else
   {
      log(img.width, 'x', img.height);
   }
}, 0);
```

I found an Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aUk9P/).

Hope it helps.